# Delphi - How to list the combination of numbers in a specific range?

Tags: delphi, random, combinations

I need to code a function in Delphi 7 that list all possible combinations of 3 integers (not repeated), using a range from 1 to 8. For example:

123 124 125 ... 412 413 415 ... 874 875 876

This function will be used for comparation purposes, so would be good if it were as fast as possible.

Please, can someone give an idea (with some code example, if possible)?

Thank you!

---

Well, here is what I got so far. Please, if someone have any tip to make it better (increase performace, reduce code, ...), please help me. Thanks again!

```
Function IsNumOnSet(Max, Num: Integer): Boolean;
var
  X, Y, Z: Integer;
Begin
  Result := False;
  For X := 1 to Max Do
    For Y := 1 to Max Do
      For Z := 1 to Max Do
        If (X <> Y) and (X <> Z) and (Y <> Z) Then
          If (IntToStr(X) + IntToStr(Y) + IntToStr(Z) = IntToStr(Num)) Then
          Begin
            Result := True;
            Exit;
          end;
end;
```

---

Here is the new and finished function, with Ken's help. It might be usefull for someone else in the future. Thank you!

```
Function IsNumOnSet(const Min, Max, Num: Integer): Boolean;
var
  X, Y, Z: Integer;
Begin
  Result := False;
  For X := Min to Max Do
    For Y := Min to Max Do
      For Z := Min to Max Do
        If (X <> Y) and (X <> Z) and (Y <> Z) Then
          If (X * 100 + Y * 10 + Z = Num) Then
          Begin
            Result := True;
            Exit;
          end;
end;
```

If someone have a better idea, please let us know!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post what you've tried so far that isn't working for you, and ask a specific question about the problem you're having with that code? "Can someone give me some code?" isn't really an acceptable question here. Thanks.

Comment: There's a Permutations section in [efg's lab](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Algorithms/).

Comment: Ken, I think I explained the problem, and I do not ask for entire code, only an idea and example... Anyway, I have added some code that I wrote, but maybe it can be changed for maximize performace. Thank you! Thank you for you too, TOndrej!

Comment: Ken, very good! Thank you!

Comment: @Ken White: Suggest you look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850355/delphi-random-combination-math/15850492#15850492 for the history.

Comment: @PeterWright: I see. Same poor question and code. Thanks.

Comment: This is a most bizarre question. At your last question I already gave you the efficient way to test if something is a valid combination. Did you not read my answer? Secondly if you want to generate all combinations do so. In which case you don't need to test.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this without a loop.

Extract the three digits in your number, check that they are different and check if they are within the min,max range.

```
uses Math;

function IsNumOnSet(min,max,num : Integer) : Boolean;
var
  d0,d1,d2 : Integer;
begin
  d0 := num mod 100;
  d1 := (num div 10) mod 10;
  d2 := num div 100;
  Result :=
    (d0 <> d1) and (d0 <> d2) and (d1 <> d2) and
    InRange(d0,min,max) and
    InRange(d1,min,max) and
    InRange(d2,min,max);
end;
```

Comment: I already said exactly this at the previous question. The message did not seem to get through.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, well here I could understand the question, which is a starter. +1 for you. BTW, I looked at the implementation of `InRange`. Not what I was expecting in a professional package. Filing a QC for improvement.

Comment: Thx. What's wrong with InRange? I can't see it from here but recall it to be inlined with two comparisons.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, current implementation is **always** testing both limits, even if the first fails.

Comment: Oh that is poor. They store to locals and then do the and. That's odd. I wonder why.

Comment: [`QC114707 Inefficient implementation of InRange`](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=114707).

Comment: @Paruba, see [`FAQ How to ask`](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for information how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little demonstration using a Litbox and an editbox.

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  mystring                                : string;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure genstrings
          (lowchar                        : char;
           highchar                       : char;
           var outstring                  : string
          );
var
  char1                                   : char;
  char2                                   : char;
  char3                                   : char;
begin
  outstring := '';
  for char1 := lowchar to highchar do
    for char2 := lowchar to highchar do
      if char1 <> char2 then
        for char3 := lowchar to highchar do
      if (char1 <> char3) and (char2 <> char3) then
        outstring := outstring + ',' + char1 + char2 + char3;
  delete(outstring,1,1)
end;


procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin with edit1 do begin
  if length(text) = 3 then
  begin
    if pos(text,mystring) > 0 then
      color := cllime
    else
      color := clred;
    if listbox1.Items.IndexOf(text) >= 0 then
      font.color := clblack
    else
      font.color := clwhite;
  end
  else
  begin
    color := claqua;
    font.Color := clfuchsia;
  end;


end;end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  genstrings('1','8',mystring);
  listbox1.Items.CommaText := mystring;
  edit1change(nil);
end;

end.
```

`genstrings` generates the strings of characters and compiles them into a comma-separated list. The list is loaded into `listbox1` - both on creating the form.

Naturally, the listbox could have been loaded directly and `listbox.commatext` used to extract the full list.

When the editbox is changed, if the text it contains is not exactly 3 characters long, then the editbox colours are changed to Fuchsia on blue.

If the string supplied is exactly 3 characters long, then two different mechanisms are used to validate the entry.

- The first validation is a simple POS into the comma-separated string of valid substrings. If the string IS found, the editbox colour is changed to lime, otherwise it is changed to red.
- The second validation is to try to find the text in the listbox (which is effectively a visible form of TStringList). If it's found, the editbox font colour is turned to black, otherwise to white.

As for speed and reliability - On such a small demonstration, speed is really of little relevance. I'd venture that the POS method is faster than the Indexof method, FWIW. The real test is what the real application is. Will a string be able to hold all of the target elements?

Naturally, an input of `7,1` for instance will hit a target in the POS implementation since '7,1' is a substring. Easily cured by `(pos... mod 5) = 1` for this demonstration, but that's a side-issue. Really depends on what we don't know - what the real purpose is. For instance, if the entry is REALLY in an editbox, and the editbox is actually a maskededit, then the entry of characters can be controlled easily.